# Explode data from MySQL field and compare with string

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with data in MySQL. 
I have a column "vacation_period" where I keep data with dates separated by commas eg. "02/10/2015,02/11/2015" and I want to explode commas, month and year. I want to make condition where I can compare month and year sent by POST with exploded data from MySQL field.

Example query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ag_vacations INNER JOIN
     ag_employees
     ON ag_vacations.user_id = ag_employees.e_id 
where ag_vacations.user_id = 1 AND 
      ag_vacations.vacation_period = 2015 AND 
      ag_vacations.vacation_period = 02
order by date_added desc
```

Comment: its never a good idea to store imploded values in database and try to condition it, btw i would recomment to store "dates" as date or datetime fields in mysql

Comment: You shouldn't keep a column called `vacation_perdiod` with a comma-delimited list of dates.  You should instead have a separate table, called a junction table, with one row per whatever (employee ?) and vacation date.  The date should be stored in the database as a proper date and not as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ag_vacations INNER JOIN
     ag_employees
     ON ag_vacations.user_id = ag_employees.e_id 
where ag_vacations.user_id = 1 AND 
      ((ag_vacations.vacation_period REGEXP '[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/2015\,[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}' AND 
      ag_vacations.vacation_period REGEXP '02\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}')
     OR (ag_vacations.vacation_period REGEXP '[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/2015' AND 
      ag_vacations.vacation_period REGEXP '[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,02\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}'))
order by date_added desc
```

so if you need to check just first date in that string `02/10/2015,02/11/2015` - you could delete OR part:

```
 OR (ag_vacations.vacation_period REGEXP '[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/2015' AND 
          ag_vacations.vacation_period REGEXP '[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,02\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}')
```

Answer (score 1):

While a string of dates is not ideal, we sometimes receive data this way. If you need to query this before you have the opportunity to clean up your schema, and if your date formats are consistent, you can query the string with `like`. In this query, we will `concat` commas to the beginning and end of the `ag_vacations.vacation_period` column to make sure we are getting the beginning of the date for month and the end of the date for year:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ag_vacations INNER JOIN
     ag_employees
     ON ag_vacations.user_id = ag_employees.e_id 
where ag_vacations.user_id = 1 AND 
      concat(ag_vacations.vacation_period,',') like '%/2015,%' AND 
      concat(',',ag_vacations.vacation_period like '%,02/%'
order by date_added desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the row, you don't need to explode in php.You can use FIND_IN_SET

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set